# Sparsity other than 0 in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, sparse-matrix

I have a huge matrix, A, that mostly contains 0 or -inf. But the negative infinity appears 100 times more often than 0. In this case changing the matrix to a 0 sparse matrix might impact the performance and memory usage adversely. But if instead, I can somehow exploit the -inf sparsity that will significantly improve the memory usage and performance(maybe) of my code. I tried to look for ways to do it pytorch but didnt find any help yet. So my question is is it really possible in pytorch or any other framework?

Comment: So, you want a way to treat a non-sparse matrix with many non-zero values with a sparse-like approach on the ground that your non-zero values are all the same (and, perhaps notably -∞). If that is correct, I would assume that this is typically not beneficial because it would be more expensive to implement matrix operations (e.g. left-/right-multiplication), and as such it is unlikely that there is a framework already implementing this. On the other hand, depending on the operations you need to perform, some sort of sparse representation may be useful, but you need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Most sparse-matrix code is built around the 0 sparsity, since it's easy to exploit it when doing calculations like matrix multiplication (a common operation in linear algebra).  Other values, especially `inf` will require very different calculations.

Comment: You guys arecorrect that matrix multiplication will be more expensive but why I want to use sparsity is to save space instead of algebraic operations. In any case if it doesnt exist, then it doesnt.